# Codeigniter error Message: Call to a member function result() on null

Tags: php, codeigniter

I Keep getting this error and do not understand what is wrong, When a user search a string it should return all messages containing that string.

This is my controller for search :

```
public function doSearch() {
$this->load->model('Messages_model');
$string = $this->input->get('string');
$data['messages']=$this->Messages_model->searchMessages($string);
$this->load->view('view_messages', $data);
}
```

My doSearch function in messages_mdoel:

```
public function searchMessages($string) {
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Messages WHERE text LIKE '%string%' ORDER BY posted_at DESC";
$query = $this->db->query($sql,$string);

if($query->num_rows() > 0) {
$messages = array();
return $query;
}

}
```

and my view_messages:

```
<?php foreach ($messages->result() as $message): ?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $message->posted_at; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $message->user_username; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $message->text; ?></td>
</tr>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Please help, thank you

Comment: This is what you're setting `$this->load->view('view_messages', $data);` and this is what you're using `foreach ($messages->result() as $message)`.  See the difference/mistake?

Answer (score 1):

Correction your sql query, your query is bellow :

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Messages WHERE text LIKE '%string%' ORDER BY posted_at DESC";
```

You used `LIKE '%string%'` but it is wrong.

it should be

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Messages WHERE text LIKE '%$string%' ORDER BY posted_at DESC";
```

and remove `$string` variable in `$query = $this->db->query($sql,$string);` like bellow :

```
$query = $this->db->query($sql);
```

More details CI `query` documentation http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html

So, final `searchMessages($string)` function in your Model :

```
<?php
public function searchMessages($string) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Messages WHERE text LIKE '%$string%' ORDER BY posted_at DESC";
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);

    if($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        //$messages = array();
        return $query;
    }
}
?>
```

Or with Query Builder Class :

```
<?php
public function searchMessages($string) {
    //$sql = "SELECT * FROM Messages WHERE text LIKE '%$string%' ORDER BY posted_at DESC";

    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('Messages');
    $this->db->like('text', $string);
    $this->db->order_by('posted_at', 'DESC');
    $query = $this->db->get();

    if($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $query;
    }
}
?>
```